# Free FM radio app for samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300)?

Tags: gratis, android, radio

I installed CyanogenMod 13 on my i9300 and noticed there is no radio app any more.

The only app on Google Play I found was Spirit1 and 2 which costs about 10 $ (hard to find others as authors (ab)use the "FM radio" description for streaming players).

Are there any free FM radio apps on Google Play that work under CM13 on i9300? Would the Samsung app work? If yes, where to get it most easily?

Answer (score 2):

[SpiritF (Spirit2 Free) Open Source Real FM Radio for AOSP+Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/spirit-fm/app-spirit2-free-source-real-fm-radio-t2951455) is free and works (at least on my SGS3 with CM13).